# Asp.net MVC4 for cross platforms/devices support

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor

We are developing application targetting for desktop , tablet, mobile devices. Is it worth to have three different pages/UI to support differnt devices?.

It was mentioned like MVC 4.0 has cross plaform(devices) support where i can write single page/solution that can be viewable by all the devices?. So is mvc4.0 really addressing this issue. If so Where can i find more relevant information on this?

From official page:

if a desktop browser requests the Home page, the application might use the `Views\Home\Index.cshtml` template. If a mobile browser requests the Home page, the application might return the `Views\Home\Index.mobile.cshtml` template.

Should i really write different cshtml for different devices?

Enhancements to Default Project Templates :- In addition to cosmetic improvements, there’s improved functionality in the new template. The template employs a technique called adaptive rendering to look good in both desktop browsers and mobile browsers without any customization.

The above one says something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features

It appears MVC4 will have a built in user-agent checker, and will allow you to have both desktop and mobile views that switch out automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target multiple devices, one of the best things you can do is use [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_Enhancement) and [Responsive Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design) principals.

This would apply to any web framework as it uses javascript and css to display your site based on the browser's dimensions and capabilities.

> Progressive enhancement is a strategy for web design that emphasizes
>   accessibility, semantic HTML markup, and external stylesheet and
>   scripting technologies. Progressive enhancement uses web technologies
>   in a layered fashion that allows everyone to access the basic content
>   and functionality of a web page, using any browser or Internet
>   connection, while also providing an enhanced version of the page to
>   those with more advanced browser software or better bandwidth.
>
> Responsive Web Design (RWD) essentially indicates that a web site is
>   crafted to use Cascading Style Sheets 3 media queries, an extension of
>   the @media rule, with fluid proportion-based grids, to adapt the
>   layout to the viewing environment, and probably also use flexible
>   images. As a result, users across a broad range of devices
>   and browsers will have access to a single source of content, laid out
>   so as to be easy to read and navigate with a minimum of resizing,
>   panning, and scrolling.

Comment: We would always like to go with microsoft technologies. So How well asp.net MVC 4.0 addresses this issue?

Comment: Different devices have different browsers ... MVC doesn't address this issue directly. The default templates do include some of this for you (modernizr, css media queries, etc), but its not actually a part of the MVC framework.